# Combine linq statement or leave

Tags: c#, linq

I have the following code. Should the linq statements be combined or left as is?
I typically like to break it up but some members on my team like a one-liner.

Thoughts?

```
        var startDate = DateTime.UtcNow;
        var endDate = startDate.AddDays(expirationDays);

        var allTokens = await repository.Query<Domain.Models.AccessToken>()
            .Where(x => !x.IsRevoked)
            .ToListAsync()
            .ConfigureAwait(false);

        var filteredTokens = allTokens.GroupBy(x => x.ApplicationName)
            .Select(y => y.OrderByDescending(z => z.ExpirationDate).FirstOrDefault())
            .Where(x => x != null && ! x.IsRevoked && x.ExpirationDate >= startDate && x.ExpirationDate <= endDate);

        return filteredTokens.Select(x => x.Id).ToList();
```

Comment: ha, that's completely up to you. Kind of hard to answer that question.

Comment: The main difference here is how much data you end up pulling from the DB and filtering in memory instead of letting the DB handle for you.

Comment: Do you need `allTokens` to be a list?  Is it a Queryable without the `ToListAsync` call?  If so, then, if you remove the `ToListAsync` call, doing it all in one go or as three separate statements is purely a matter of taste.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Personally, I follow the mantra, "Programs must be written for people to read, and only incidentally for machines to execute" (Harold Abelson.)  Make the code as readable as possible (and only then worry about optimizations/efficiency/etc if needed).  It's easier to optimize clean code than it is to clean up optimized code.

So on that important readability front, I'd say: Break them Up!  Breaking up your LINQ statements into multiple lines lets you do something very very valuable:

```
var records = someLinqStatement;
var activeUserRecords = records.SomeLinqStatement;
var mostRecentUserRecords = activeUserRecords.SomeLinqStatement;
```

... it lets you use the *variable name* to document the contents of the linq.  You're using it to improve the readability of your code.  If anything, *you've* grouped too much (there's a *lot* going on in that 3-line filteredTokens line in your version.)

Trying to read what your coworkers would have:

```
var allTokens = await repository.Query<Domain.Models.AccessToken>()
        .Where(x => !x.IsRevoked)
        .ToListAsync()
        .ConfigureAwait(false)
        .GroupBy(x => x.ApplicationName)
        .Select(y => y.OrderByDescending(z => z.ExpirationDate).FirstOrDefault())
        .Where(x => x != null && ! x.IsRevoked && x.ExpirationDate >= startDate && x.ExpirationDate <= endDate)
        .Select(x => x.Id).ToList();
```

... is a freaking nightmare.  At that point, I'm no longer *reading* code, I'm slowly trying to *decipher* it.

Comment: This also makes it easy to view intermediate results when debugging.